# SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR Error - no method from app referenced

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, segmentation-fault

There is no method from my app referenced in this crash report, and I have not been able to reproduce it. Several of my users are having the same crash. I can't find any tableview cells with a scrollview or any place where I use a spring. Where could this crash be coming from?

```
Incident Identifier: 748D4582-3868-42BD-BF98-B3B47895954D
CrashReporter Key:   F7F44964-E877-4C7A-881C-91EBC4261080
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:         MyApp [2415]
Path:            /Users/USER/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      com.mycom.myapp
Version:         1.5.1
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-11-21 05:30:47 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x5000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3921fb66 objc_msgSend + 5
1   UIKit                                0x3177e315 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 409
2   UIKit                                0x317266cd -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1800
3   UIKit                                0x31719f75 -[UITableView _visibleCells] + 24
4   UIKit                                0x31783f13 -[UITableView indexPathForCell:] + 26
5   UIKit                                0x31782289 -[UITableViewCell _canDoSeparatorLayout] + 64
6   UIKit                                0x31781e19 -[UITableViewCell _updateSeparatorContent] + 56
7   UIKit                                0x31844a3b -[UITableViewCell _updateViewsForDeleteButton] + 218
8   UIKit                                0x3171c673 -[UITableViewCellScrollView setContentOffset:] + 186
9   UIKit                                0x31880561 __43-[UITableViewCell _animateSwipeCancelation]_block_invoke + 81
10  UIKit                                0x31681113 +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 490
11  UIKit                                0x317a66ef +[UIView _animateUsing WithDuration:delay:options:mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:animations:start:completion:] + 166
12  UIKit                                0x317a663f +[UIView _animateUsingSpringWithDuration:delay:options:mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:animations:completion:] + 90
13  UIKit                                0x318804bf -[UITableViewCell _animateSwipeCancelation] + 278
14  UIKit                                0x31850639 -[UITableView _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:] + 216
15  UIKit                                0x31901873 -[UITableView willMoveToSuperview:] + 62
16  UIKit                                0x318e1913 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 151
17  UIKit                                0x3164a091 -[UIView removeFromSuperview] + 56
18  UIKit                                0x3171e431 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 64
19  UIKit                                0x3164c9b3 -[UIView dealloc] + 366
20  libobjc.A.dylib                      0x39221023 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 359
21  CoreFoundation                       0x2edfb1c9 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
22  CoreFoundation                       0x2ee90e83 __CFRunLoopRun + 1315
23  CoreFoundation                       0x2edfb471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
24  CoreFoundation                       0x2edfb253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
25  GraphicsServices                     0x33b352eb GSEventRunModal + 138
26  UIKit                                0x316b0845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
27  MyApp                          0x000e810b main (main.m:5)
28  libdyld.dylib                        0x3971dab7 start + 3

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x397c1838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3970a623 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 39

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x397d4c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x39838cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x397d4c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x39838cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x397d4c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x39838cc4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x397c1a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                       0x2ee92559 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 157
2   CoreFoundation                       0x2ee90c79 __CFRunLoopRun + 793
3   CoreFoundation                       0x2edfb471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
4   CoreFoundation                       0x2ee3f0db CFRunLoopRun + 98
5   CoreMotion                           0x2f4b3369 CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 57225
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3983ac5d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3983abcf _pthread_start + 102
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x39838cd0 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    pc: 0x3921fb66     r7: 0x27d21618     sp: 0x27d215f4     r0: 0x17f82270 
    r1: 0x31c343d7     r2: 0x189d9e00     r3: 0x17d46730     r4: 0x189d9e00 
    r5: 0x00000338     r6: 0x17e0e340     r8: 0x39e43294     r9: 0x50000000 
   r10: 0x17d46730    r11: 0x000001d0     ip: 0x39d3e220     lr: 0x3177e315 
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I can see looking at the crash report:

1. The crash is caused bei `SIGSEGV` in `objc_msgSend`. This means the app is trying to send a message to an object that is invalid. This means you have at least one memory problem in your app (somewhere).
2. It looks like the problem happens when trying to delete a row in a tableView using the swipe to delete gesture, see `-[UITableView _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:]` showing up in the stack trace and additional hints above like `-[UITableViewCell _animateSwipeCancelation]`, `-[UITableViewCell _updateViewsForDeleteButton]`.

So it might be worth a try checking this use case in all table views in your app.

In addition use the `Analyze` feature of Xcode and fix all warnings it shows and also try running your app with `Enable Zombie Objects` set. There a lots of websites and also answers here on SO explaining how to do that.

Comment: thanks so much. I will keep trying to reproduce the issue. Is the reason for the error, then, that the object that I am trying to delete is invalid?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the object you are trying to delete that is invalid. Something is invalid.

Comment: Also, I do use Analyze and Zombie objects. It's just hard trying to figure out where to start with an error such as this, when the invalid object could be anything. I will keep trying to reproduce. Thanks again.

Comment: will enableZombieObjects help me to see results in my crash logs if I create an .ipa with zombieObjects enabled? I want to test this on my phone apart from being plugged into a computer, and I find the best way to do that is through .ipa's.

Comment: You should only enable Zombie objects when debugging with Xcode attached to find such cases. Never enable it in test versions or even app store version. Never! It won't help with crash reports either.

Comment: Never in an app store version of course! But what about a test version where the only tester is me?

Comment: It only helps with the debugger attached.

Comment: You don't see any other clues that could point me more specifically where to look, do you? I have swiped and deleted everything 15 times all over the app, every scenario I can think of, and I still can't replicate this bad boy!